# Ideas for generating random lobulated pulmonary nodule contours

Tags: matlab, geometry, computational-geometry, shapes

I need to generate random lobulated contours such as the following[image]

Any ideas or algorithms on how to do this ??
The software I am going to use is matlab, however I have no problem if you post solutions in other languages too...

p.s I only need to plot a random contour that resembles the above...

Comment: Voting to reopen. It's simple to provide an answer short enough for the format, and - although there may be several variations - there is only one basic answer. The answer set is narrow and the issue can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
degree = 5;
numPoints = 1000;
blobWidth = 5;    

theta = 0:(2*pi)/(numPoints-1):2*pi;

coeffs = rand(degree,1);
rho = zeros(size(theta));
for i = 1:degree
    rho = rho + coeffs(i)*sin(i*theta);
end

phase = rand*2*pi;

[x,y] = pol2cart(theta+phase, rho+blobWidth);
plot(x,y)
axis equal 
set(gca,'Visible','off')
```

[image: Blob]

You can control the <strike>wiggliness</strike> lobulacrity by modifying `degree`. I think 5 gives something about as <strike>wiggly</strike> lobulacious as your example.

That was fun - hope it helps!

Comment: I would like to make one more question... how can i introduce a extra smaller noisy variations on the contour you produce ??

Comment: could you please provide me with some versy short explanation of how the code you posted works??

Answer (score 4):

Here is one idea.

```
step = 0.1;
r_min = 0.5;
r_max = 1.0;
ir = 35;
tt = linspace(0, 2*pi, ir);
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 5*ir);

rr = r_min + (r_max - r_min)*rand(1, length(tt));
rr(end) = rr(1);
r = interp1(tt, rr, t, 'spline');
// add some noise of magnitude N
N = 0.1;
noise = -N + 2*N*rand(1, length(r));
noise(1:2:end) = 0.0;
r = r + noise;
// 
hp = polar(t, r);
set(hp, 'LineWidth', 2)

h = findall(gca,'type','line');
h(h == hp) = [];
delete(h);
t = findall(gca,'type','text');
delete(t);
delete(findall(gca, 'FaceColor', [1 1 1]))
```

Typical output looks like this (ir = 10, without noise)

[image: randomly generated planar closed curve]

or this (ir = 35, with and without noise)

[image: randomly generated planar closed curve perturbed by noise]

Comment: I would like to make one more question... how can i introduce a extra smaller noisy variations on the contour you produce ??

Comment: @obelix I edited my answer to add a parameter `N` that you can use as noise magnitude. If you don't want noise, you can set N = 0.0 or comment out the relevant lines in the code. Hope that helps.