# Documenting matlab code for generating random shapes

Tags: matlab, shapes

Can you please help me document this Matlab code that is supposed to produce random shapes?? The wiggliness of the shapes is supposed to be controlled by the variable degree...

But how the rho (radius values) are produced... I can't really get it....

```
degree = 5;
numPoints = 1000;
blobWidth = 5;    

theta = 0:(2*pi)/(numPoints-1):2*pi;

coeffs = rand(degree,1);
rho = zeros(size(theta));
for i = 1:degree
    rho = rho + coeffs(i)*sin(i*theta);
end

phase = rand*2*pi;

[x,y] = pol2cart(theta+phase, rho+blobWidth);
plot(x,y)
axis equal 
set(gca,'Visible','off')
```

Comment: You should add a link to the source of this code...

Comment: another user posted this to me, in stackoverflow but never replied when I asked for an explanation

Comment: then please add a link to that question

Comment: @obelix Sorry I couldn't respond to your request in time - I was on holiday for a few days. Looks like @ Dan and @ patrik have given you as good an explanation of my code as I could have done! [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932746/ideas-for-generating-random-lobulated-pulmonary-nodule-contours/22937709#22937709) the original question, for those interested.

Comment: @SamRoberts Great answer to that previous question btw, very clever code! I must say that the other spline code is also really smart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
theta = 0:(2*pi)/(numPoints-1):2*pi;
```

So this is just a vector of angles in a revolution, if you plot this theta against a constant rho (after calling `pol2cart`) you will get a circle:

```
r = ones(size(theta));
[x,y] = pol2cart(theta, r);
plot(x,y)
axis equal
```

This should be obvious if you understand what `pol2cart` does because you have a series of all the angles in a circle and a constant radius for all of them. If you don't understand that (i.e. polar coordinates) then that's a very basic mathematical concept you need to go and read up on your own before trying to understand this code.

OK so now a circle in cartesian coords is just a line in polar coords (i.e. plot(theta, r) noting that the horizontal axis now represents angle and the vertical represents radius). So if we want to randomly mess up our circle, we could randomly mess up our line. Using `sin` does this in a nice smooth way. Adding random frequencies of many `sin` waves adds less and less predictable "jitter". I think it would help you to understand if you add the following line to your code:

```
rho = zeros(size(theta));
hold all
for i = 1:degree
    rho = rho + coeffs(i)*sin(i*theta);
    plot(theta, rho)
end
```

and contrast this to (be sure to close your figure window before running this)

```
rho = zeros(size(theta));
hold all
for i = 1:degree
    rho = rho + coeffs(i)*sin(i*theta);
    plot(theta, coeffs(i)*sin(i*theta))
end
```

The second one shows you the different frequencies of `sin` waves used and the first shows how these sum to create unpredictable wavy lines. Now think of the `pol2rect` function as bending these lines around to make a "circle". If the line is dead straight you get a perfect circle, if it's wavy you get a "wavy" circle.

`degree` in your code just controls how many `sin` waves to add up.

finally `phase = rand*2*pi;` just randomly rotates your shape after it has been created.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this was an amazing piece of code! But regarding rho. What is done is that you have a circle with base radius of 5 (`blobwidth`) and then you have a random offset `coeffs`. Then the offset is added to `rho` in `rho = rho + coeffs(i)*sin(i*theta);`. This means that the first loop an offset is added to the circle with frequency 1Hz. This then yields a constant offset. The next loop the frequency increases to 2Hz. Then the offset will be added to every second point and the offset may be negative as well. Then it goes on like this. Finally the coordinate is transformed to polar.

A few comments though. The most readable and the easiest way to create theta is to use linspace. And also, since rho is overwritten in the loop, you may as well define it just as `rho = 0;`

Comment: I would call `coeffs(i)` an offset but rather an amplitude. If you add all those `sin` waves up their expected value should still be `0`, i.e. there is no actual "offset" (which usually refers to a constant offset)

Comment: Thanks @patrik, glad you liked my code! You're right about `linspace` - I never remember to use that. About `rho`, though - I don't agree. Best practice would always be to preallocate a variable at the size that it's eventually going to be, otherwise it will need to slow down to reallocate memory when it changes size. If you put `rho=0`, you (nearly) may as well not preallocate at all.

Comment: @SamRoberts Hi, by doing rho = rho + coeffs(i)*sin(i*theta); You still do just one memory allocation. Just try it. loop through it a number of times. You will actually notice that rho = 0; is slightly faster since matlab have some good ways of doing this. The only reason for rho = zeros(size(theta)); would be to point out the size of `rho`. And for `rho=0`: this is no preallocation. You just define the variable to avoid an error.

Comment: @patrik My tests show the opposite of that. Preallocating rho with the correct size gives a clear speedup. Happy to share the code for my tests so we can compare - we must be doing different things.

Comment: Yes that would be good. clear; degree = 5; numPoints = 1000; blobWidth = 5;      theta = 0:(2*pi)/(numPoints-1):2*pi;  coeffs = rand(degree,1); tic for k = 1:100000 rho=0; for i = 1:degree     rho = rho + coeffs(i)*sin(i*theta); end end toc and change rho for preallocation. However the code must have this structure to be comparable, best to run right after eachother. It may though as well have to do with matlab version and operative system

Comment: function mytestpreallocrho

x = rand(1e3);

totaltime1 = 0;

for i = 1:1000
    
    clear rho;
    
    rho = 0;
    
    t = tic;
    rho = rho+x;
    rho(1) = 0;
    totaltime1 = totaltime1 + toc(t);
    
end

totaltime2 = 0;

for i = 1:1000
    
    clear rho;
    
    rho = zeros(size(x));
    
    t = tic;
    rho = rho+x;
    rho(1) = 0;
    totaltime2 = totaltime2 + toc(t);
    
end
    
totaltime1
totaltime2

Comment: @patrik Code in previous comment. Note that i) You *have* to do this within a function, otherwise the MATLAB JIT will not be in effect. ii) I've included a statement `rho(1)=0`. This forces MATLAB to actually make a copy of the right-hand side, otherwise it will be a lazy copy. For me, `totaltime1` is reliably about 1.7 secs, `totaltime2` is reliably about 0.45 secs.